# ob_start() error running Devel on Search API + Search views page

Tags: 7, search, debugging

How can I run Devel on search pages?  I keep getting an ob_start() error.  How can I run debug on these search pages.

The error is:

Fatal error: Unknown: Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran my Devel debug on blocks and that worked.